# Overriding expired contact session lock for contact id

Tags: redis

Sitecore 9.1

We recently moved to Redis in Azure for session. When session is unavailable for a short period of time, the I see the logs below for 10's of thousands of lines. Other than Redis never being unavailable, any way to resolve these warnings?

> 7548 22:46:38 WARN  Overriding expired contact session lock for contact id: e7bb97ee-1d98-4b1f-814c-d0c797a60a66

Comment: Any further news on this subject? We are getting 2.5M/hr of these in our Azure logs.

Comment: I saw this after upgrading my XC VM. My interpretation is that since XC was not gracefully shut down, there was a backlog of processing / errors.